# What is the difference between Generate Signed APK and gradle's assemble<flavor>Release command

Tags: android, gradle, proguard, dagger-2, dagger

I am experiencing the following situation:
-> When I build the APK (release version) using `Generate Signed APK` option, the APK works perfectly, all the libraries seems included.

-> On the other hand, if I build the APK from gradle command using `gradle assemble{flavor}Release`, the output APK doesn't keep all the classes and crashes with the following log (which is from one of the libraries that I included)(the CI job uses the assemble command):

> Caused by java.lang.ClassNotFoundException Didn't find class
>   "dagger.internal.Preconditions" on path: DexPathList[[zip file
>   ,nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/XYZ, /system/lib64,
>   /system/vendor/lib64]] XYZ.DaggerChatComponent$Builder.XYZModule

What is the difference between Generate Signed APK and gradle's assemble{flavor}Release command?

Answer (score 0):

The difference is when you `Generate Signed APK` you choose `Release` flavor, then you sign it. That's the right procedure. but when you use `gradleassemble{flavor}Release` you are just choosing `Release` and you don't sign it. but `Release` flavor by default needs signing. then it throws that error.

Comment: thanks for the info. But why does it crash in gradle one?